# Is there a simple way to create a custom LaTeX environment template?

Tags: latex, auctex

I'm writing lots of LaTeX `beamer` slides with AUCTeX. Each slide starts as follows:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\secname}
\framesubtitle{\subsecname}

\end{frame}
```

Is there a simple way to bind this template to a custom key command?

Comment: You could use `yasnippet` and insert stuff like that.  Or, you could use:  `(defun hello-world () (interactive) (insert "\\begin{frame}\n\\frametitle{\\secname}\n\\framesubtitle{\\subsecname}\n\n\\end{frame}"))`  And any keyboard shortcut that floats your boat:  `(global-set-key [f5] 'hello-world)` and you can use `major-mode` or `minor-mode` keyboard shortcuts or ...  There are just a ton of possibilities ...

Answer (score 3):

I think it would be easier to add something like this to your `.emacs` and then go the usual <kbd>C-c C-e frame RET</kbd> route.  The code below tweaks the definition of `frame` in `beamer.el` and gives you the chance to add a new `frametitle` and `framesubtitle`, otherwise it just adds `\frametitle{\secname}` and `\framesubtitle{\subsecname}` as requested.

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "beamer"
  (defun beamer-frame-env-with-subtitle ()
    (setq LaTeX-environment-list
          (assq-delete-all (car (assoc "frame" (LaTeX-environment-list)))
                            LaTeX-environment-list))
    (LaTeX-paragraph-commands-add-locally "framesubtitle")
    (LaTeX-add-environments
     '("frame" (lambda (env &rest ignore)
                 (let ((title (TeX-read-string "(Optional) Title: " nil
                                               'LaTeX-beamer-frametitle-history))
                       (subtitle (TeX-read-string "(Optional) Subtitle: ")))
                   (LaTeX-insert-environment env)
                   (save-excursion
                     (LaTeX-find-matching-begin)
                     (end-of-line)
                     (LaTeX-newline)
                     (indent-according-to-mode)
                     (if (zerop (length title))
                         (insert "\\frametitle{\\secname}")
                       (insert (format "\\frametitle{%s}" title))
                       ;; This works because \frametitle is a
                       ;; paragraph command.
                       (backward-char)
                       (LaTeX-fill-paragraph)))
                   (if (zerop (length subtitle))
                       (insert "\\frametitle{\\subsecname}")
                     (insert (format "\\framesubtitle{%s}" subtitle))
                     (LaTeX-fill-paragraph))
                   (LaTeX-newline)
                   (indent-according-to-mode)))))
    ;; Fontification
    (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
               (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
      (font-latex-add-keywords '(("framesubtitle" "<[{"))
                               'slide-title)
      (font-latex-update-font-lock t)))
  (beamer-frame-env-with-subtitle)
  (add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook #'beamer-frame-env-with-subtitle t))
```

Note that you should have

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

in order to make this work.